# adding buttons to array/struct?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a struct and when run, they are shown in the tableviewcells as in these pictures:

[image: pict1]
[image: pict2]

Is it possible to have the "toppings" (let countries,let cheeses, let veges) be added as buttons instead of string/text within the cell? I have tried quite a few different solutions, but I think Ive got it wrong somehow. If they were buttons then I could add a function to the buttons/cells, and add the title of the button to the textfield below the tableviews.
(in the "document outline" the cells only have a content view)
Hope my question makes sense

```
import UIKit

class CountriesTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count:Int?
        
        if tableView == self.tableView1 {
            count = countries.count
        }
  
        if tableView == self.tableView2 {
            count = cheeses.count
        }
        
        if tableView == self.tableView3 {
            count = veges.count
        }
            
        return count!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell?
    
    
    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryCell", for: indexPath)
    let country = countries[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.text = country.name
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = country.isoCode
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: country.isoCode)
    }
    
    if tableView == self.tableView2 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheCell", for: indexPath)
    let che = cheeses[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = che.name
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = che.isoCode
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: che.isoCode)
        
    }
    
    if tableView == self.tableView3 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VegeCell", for: indexPath)
    let veg = veges[indexPath.row]
            cell!.textLabel!.text = veg.name
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = veg.isoCode
            cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: veg.isoCode)
        }
    return cell!
    
    }

    
    
    
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView3: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
    
  
    
    
    
        
        struct cheese {
        var isoCode: String
        var name: String
    }
    
    let countries = [
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "Bacon"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "CHORIZO"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "Cocktail Pølser"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "Kalve"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "KEBAB"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "KYL"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "OKSEKØD"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "PEPPERONI"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "PARMA"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "SKINKE"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "TUN"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "REJER"),
    ]
    let cheeses = [
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "OST"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "FRISK MOZZA"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "CHEDDAR"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "GORGONZOLA"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "PARMESAN"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "FETA"),
    ]
    
    let veges = [
        cheese(isoCode: "s", name: "FRISK TOMAT"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "CHERRY TOMAT"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "CHAMPIGNON"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "LØG"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "ANANAS"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "MAJS"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "OLIVEN"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "G. PEBERFRUGT"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "R. PEBERFRUGT"),
        cheese(isoCode: "", name: "JALAPEÑOS"),
        
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView1.dataSource = self
        tableView1.delegate = self
        //        tableView1.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountryCell")
        
        tableView2.dataSource = self
        tableView2.delegate = self
        //        tableView2.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CheCell")
        
        tableView3.dataSource = self
        tableView3.delegate = self
        //        tableView3.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "VegeCell")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

            
    @IBOutlet weak var showTopping: UITextField!
    @IBAction func addTopping(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
        
            self.showTopping.text = sender.currentTitle
//        }
//    @IBAction func removeTopping(_ sender: UIButton) {
//        append.self.showTopping.text = sender.currentTitle
    }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Cell, Once this is done you can make the cells buttons and add anything else you would like within a cell. There is unlimited functionality with custom cell class.

Comment: But those are custom cells - three in fact! one in each tableview. I would like the toppings/items of my array to show as buttons instead of text in a content view?

Comment: Yes make a custom cell to do this, its the only way. then you could make functions for your custom cell and do something like `cell.addText` which would make the cell a button with whatever text you pass to it. Then you would reuse this custom cell for all 3 tableViews because they take in the same type of information